# Moving an entire directory using .htaccess fails for individual files

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to 301 .htaccess an entire directory INCLUDING all the files within that directory.....if I use this string:

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,R=301]
```

> Running the below is successful....

website.com/old/ redirects to website.com/new/

> Running the below is NOT successful....(error 404)

website.com/old/page-123.php does NOT redirect to website.com/new/

So, individual files within that directory throw a 404 error....any ideas why?

Worth mentioning as well that I have the following rules above:

```
<files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# All pages www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# below to force https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.my-site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: @anubhava - yes I do - I've added them to the questions

Comment: But I don't see your `old->new` rule in this .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava - old->new rule would be at the end (bottom) of the .htaccess

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` and test it after clearing browser cache

Comment: @anubhava - no joy. thanks all the same thou....

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
RewriteRule ^old/* https://www.my-site.com/new/ [R=301,L]
```

Hope that helps someone :)